# how do I use the swup library on a template with these Laravel links?

Tags: laravel-blade, swup

I'm working on a project where the template has swup for page transitions. Using the template alone, everything works fine, but after adjusting my links with laravel, it doesn't work. Pages are always reloaded.

```
<div id="footer-bar" class="footer-bar-1 footer-bar-detached">
    <a href="{{ route('store') }}" class="{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() === 'store' ? 'active-nav' : '' }} a-link"><i class="bi bi-cart"></i><span>Magasin</span></a>
    <a href="{{ route('statements') }}" class="{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() === 'statements' ? 'active-nav' : '' }} a-link"><i class="bi bi-graph-up"></i><span>Mes paiements</span></a>
    <a href="{{ route('home') }} " class="circle-nav-2 a-link"><i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i><span>Home</span></a>
    <a href="{{ route('payments.index') }}" class="{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() === 'payments' ? 'active-nav' : '' }} a-link"><i class="bi bi-receipt"></i><span>Payments</span></a>
    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#menu-sidebar"><i class="bi bi-three-dots"></i><span>More</span></a>
</div>
```

and swup code in my template

```
 if(isAJAX === true){
    if(window.location.protocol !== "file:"){
        const options = {
            containers: ["#page"],
            cache:false,
            animateHistoryBrowsing: false,
            plugins: [
                new SwupPreloadPlugin()
            ],
            linkSelector:'a:not(.external-link):not(.default-link):not([href^="https"]):not([href^="http"]):not([data-gallery])'
        };
        const swup = new Swup(options);
        document.addEventListener('swup:pageView',(e) => { init_template(); })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's [route](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-route) helper by default returns absolute urls including the hostname, which, depending on how swup is configured, will bypass swup and load the links directly. The `linkSelector` in your config includes `:not([href^="https"])`, basically preventing any absolute urls from being handled by swup even if they match the current origin.

Passing in `false` for the third optional `$absolute` parameter will output just the pathname, re-enabling swup for those links.

```html
<a href="{{ route('store', [], false) }}">
```